# Can you model an interface where only it's descendants can be implemented?

Tags: c#

Assume the following code:

```
namespace Example {
  public interface IBase {
    string CommonMember { get; set; }
  }

  public interface IDerived : IBase {
    void DoSomething();
  }

  public interface IComplexDerived : IBase {
    IEnumerable<object> Junk { get; }
  }
}
```

I have a similar structure in the project I'm currently working on. The interface `IBase` primarily serves the purpose to be able to keep instances of `IDerived` and `IComplexDerived` in the same container (like a `List<IBase>`) and also not having to repeat common interface member definitions (like `CommonMember` in the example).

One way this would then be used would be something like this:

```
public class Foo {
  public void Bar( IEnumerable<IBase> instances ) {
    foreach( IBase instance in instances ) {
      if( instance is IDerived ) { /* do something */ } 
      else if( instance is IComplexDerived ) {  /* do something else */ }
    }
  }
}
```

So, nothing would stop the user from implementing `IBase` and passing instances of that class into the system. But doing that would be completely useless because the whole library only expects to deal with classes that implement interfaces that were *derived* from `IBase`.

This concept is of course fully documented and shouldn't cause any problems. However, I was wondering if it would be possible to communicate this through means of the language itself. Like having an abstract class, but for interfaces.

You might ask why not simply use an abstract class then. The reason for that is that we don't want to impose the requirement to inherit from our class.

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to design something like this. You have a common interface but you still have to check the type to decide which code to execute. What would you do if someone created a third interface that is derived from `IBase` and implements this? Or if *you* want to introduce said third interface? You would have to adjust all *consumers* of `IBase`.

Comment: What is the use of interfaces if you are still checking for specific types? An interface itself has much in common with an abstract class, since you cannot instantiate it. I guess you just have to tell your users (the programmers) not to implement IBase directly. And you may want to do some runtime checking, although I wouldn't spent too much code on that.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Good point. I'll see if I can come up with a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is feasible in your actual case, but I think you could have

- `IComplexDerived` inherit from `IDerived` instead of `IBase`.
- You would then have a list of `IDerived` instead of `IBase`, so even a new implementation of `IBase` would not type-check (since you require an `IEnumerable<IDerived>`)
- Your classes inheriting from `IComplexDerived` would simply implement `DoSomething()` in a different way. By doing this you would let your `Bar` method decide polymorphically what DoSomething it needs to call (and avoid checking on the type)

I mean something like this:

```
  public interface IBase {
    string CommonMember { get; set; }
  }

  public interface IDerived : IBase {
    void DoSomething();
  }

  //IComplexDerived isnow a IDerived    
  public interface IComplexDerived : IDerived { 
    IEnumerable<object> Junk { get; }
  }

public class Foo 
{
  // Bar requires IEnumerable<IDerived> so you can't call it with a collection
  // of classes implementing IBase
  public void Bar( IEnumerable<IDerived> instances ) {
    foreach( IDerived instance in instances ) {
        instance.DoSomething(); // DoSomething will "do something else" in 
                                // classes implementing IComplexDerived
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution even though I went with a completely different approach as suggested in the comments.

Comment: @oliversalzburg if you come up with a better solution you can add an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: Sure, I just feel that my solution is very specific to my case and not really helpful to future visitors. But, you're right, I'll add what I ended up with as an answer for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to remove the common interface from `IDerived` and `IComplexDervied` and create a wrapper class which takes an instance of one of them and provides the common functionality:

```
public interface IDerived
{
    void DoSomething();
    string CommonMember { get; set; }
}

public interface IComplexDerived
{
    IEnumerable<object> Junk { get; }
    string CommonMember { get; set; }
}

public class EitherDerived : IBase
{
    private readonly IDerived derived;
    private readonly IComplexDerived complex;
    private readonly bool isComplex;

    public EitherDerived(IDerived derived)
    {
        this.derived = derived;
        this.isComplex = false;
    }

    public EitherDerived(IComplexDerived complex)
    {
        this.complext = complex;
        this.isComplex = true;
    }

    public string CommonMember
    {
        get
        {
            return isComplex ? complex.CommonMember : derived.CommonMember;
        }
        set
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    public TOut Either<TOut>(Func<IDerived, TOut> mapDerived, Func<IComplexDerived, TOut> mapComplex)
    {
        return isComplex ? mapComplex(complex) : mapDerived(derived);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class instead of your `IBase` interface if you want to be sure you are dealing with one of those classes:

```
private object HandleDerived(IDerived derived) { ... }
private object HandleComplex(IComplexDerived complex) { ... }

public void Bar(IEnumerable<EitherDerived> instances)
{
    foreach(var either in instances)
    {
        object _ = either.SelectEither(HandleDerived, HandleComplex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to look for a different design altogether was what I ended up doing. Since this is an open source project, we can look at the actual results.

- `IBase` is [`ITimelineTrackBase`](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/TimeBeam/blob/8ac29288fb215cb88f0ba52b3b7c490974248827/TimeBeam/ITimelineTrackBase.cs) and describes interface members that are common to all derived types.
- `IDerived` is [`ITimelineTrack`](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/TimeBeam/blob/8ac29288fb215cb88f0ba52b3b7c490974248827/TimeBeam/ITimelineTrack.cs) and it describes a track on a timeline which consists of a single element with a start and end.
- `IComplexDerived` is [`IMultiPartTimelineTrack`](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/TimeBeam/blob/8ac29288fb215cb88f0ba52b3b7c490974248827/TimeBeam/IMultiPartTimelineTrack.cs) and it describes a track on a timeline which consists of multiple elements that each have a start and an end.

Contrary to my earlier plans, I'm not storing these in a `List<IBase>`, but I'm using `List<IComplexDerived>`. Or, in terms of the application, a `List<IMultiPartTimelineTrack>`.

Now I decided to not accept an `IBase` anywhere if that's not what I actually want to support in that method. So the `ITimelineTrackBase` is used purely as a base interface and isn't offered as an accepted parameter type anywhere in the library.

Instead the whole library deals either with single track elements (`ITimelineTrack`) or a collection of those (`IMultiPartTimelineTrack`). As needed, the former is wrapped into the latter by a helper construct [`SingleTrackToMultiTrackWrapper`](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/TimeBeam/blob/8ac29288fb215cb88f0ba52b3b7c490974248827/TimeBeam/Surrogates/SingleTrackToMultiTrackWrapper.cs).

So instead of making it impossible to implement the interface, I just made it pointless to implement it.